# Unable to display icon in React Bootstrap Tab instead of text

Tags: reactjs, icons, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap's Tabs and I am stuck with an issue where I am unable to pass icon into the title prop
    because its is displayed as [Object][Object], any thoughts on this ?

```
const tabsInstance = (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1}>
    <Tab eventKey={1} title={`Tab1 ${<i class=" icon-remove"></i>}`}>Tab 1 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>Tab 3 content</Tab>
  </Tabs>
);
```

Output is displayed as:

> Tab1 [Object][Object] Tab 2 Tab 3

How to display `icon` in the tab instead of `Title`?

======UPDATE=====
Output displayed after suggestion.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<Tab eventKey={1} title={`Tab1 ${<i class=" icon-remove"></i>}`}>Tab 1 content</Tab>
```

The problem is that template literal will try to evaluate React Object (transpiled by babel JSX syntax) to a string, that's why you get: `Tab1 [Object][Object]`. So in the end, you are passing a String as a `title` prop.

To solve it pass a React object this way:

```
<Tab eventKey={1} title={<span>Tab1 <i className=" icon-remove" /> </span>}>Tab 1 content</Tab>
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to reply but its not working..:/  

Output in the chrome inspect element:
<span><!-- react-text: 75 -->Tab1 <!-- /react-text --><i></i><!-- react-text: 77 --> <!-- /react-text --></span>

Comment: You mean this is the title? That's weird because title should accept a Node https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-props-pane

Comment: yeah correct. This is what I see. Wish I can paste the screenshot in comment section unable to

Comment: @johnsam use className on icon instead class.

Answer (score 4):

did you tried this? hope this can help you

```
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/lib/fa/";


<Tab
  eventKey={1}
  title={
   <span>
     <FaTrash />{" "}
   </span>
  }
>
    Tab 1 content
</Tab>
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3v55nn0j41)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs'
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const clock = <i class="fa fa-Clock"></i>
        return (
            <div>
                <Tabs id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                    <Tab  title={<span>{clock} Home</span>}>
                        Your Component
                    </Tab>
                    
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```